# Hardware Timestamping Intel x550 and Npcap

Tags: timestamp, npcap

Is it possible to get all recieved packets with hardware timestamp through NPCAP (Windows) and using an Intel® Ethernet Controller X550?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get all recieved packets with hardware timestamp through NPCAP

Currently, no.  Npcap doesn't support getting hardware time stamps from the system and using them as time stamps for packets.  It might be possible to make the Npcap driver support that (there are already libpcap APIs that could be used if driver support is added), but it has not yet been done.  See [Npcap issue #581](https://github.com/nmap/npcap/issues/581).